# what's the difference of xs:element and s:element

Tags: xml, web-services, xsd

I'm writing code to consume a web service. In the wsdl,all the element type is S, is there any difference between xs:element and s:element? Thx.

```
<s:element name="UpdateRecipeStatus">
    <s:complexType>
       <s:sequence>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="formID" type="s:string"/>
          <s:element minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" name="formStatus" type="s:string"/>
       </s:sequence>
    </s:complexType>
</s:element>
```

Comment: they are just different namespaces. do you know what namespaces are? is this in the same file, or in different files?

Comment: Namespace prefixes only have meaning *locally*. You need to find where the namespace declarations are. If `xmlns:s` and `xmlns:xs` are followed by the same namespace URI then, from an information perspective, they're identical.

Answer (score 0):

Look for the namespace declarations in the form `xmlns:s="some-namespace-uri"` or `xmlns:xs="some-other-namespace-uri"`. It's the namespace URI that matters, not the short prefix. If the two prefixes `s` and `xs` are bound to the same namespace URI, then they mean the same thing.

In XSD schemas, most people use either "xs" or "xsd" as the namespace prefix, by convention. But if you want to save space and/or confuse your readers, then using "s" or "Ψ" is perfectly legal.